# Convert utc time string to date object

Tags: datetime, d3.js

I have time string as below:

```
2022-06-20T19:00:00.1620000Z
```

I try below code to convert it to datetime object but it return null

```js
    var t1 = d3.timeParse("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%LZ")("2022-06-20T19:00:00.1620000Z")
    console.log("debug:",t1)
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v7.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, mind the `T` between the day and the hour.

The issue here is that you're using `%L`, which accepts milliseconds (from `000` to `999`), when you should be using `%f` for microseconds. But even if you use `%f` you have a problem: your string has **seven** decimal places for seconds, and `%f` accepts only six. Therefore, you have to trim that string, using whatever method you like.

For instance (look at your browser's console, not the snippet console):

```js
let t = "2022-06-20T19:00:00.1620000Z";
t = t.slice(0, -2) + t.slice(-1);
const t1 = d3.timeParse("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ")(t)
console.log("debug:",t1)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/7.4.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks, what does the T and Z mean?

Comment: Have a look here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Times